# Recenter cursor in middle of screen when editing in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I dislike having to edit near the bottom of my screen. This happens a lot in Xcode when editing near the end of a file. In other editors (such as vim or sublime) you can recenter the editing point vertically to the middle of the screen.

Is there a shortcut to do this in Xcode?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way in XCode to do this. It doesn't let you scroll past the bottom of the file. [Here](http://www.1729.us/xcode/Xcode%20Shortcuts.pdf) is a great list of shortcuts that do exist though.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, and as mentioned in the comments, Xcode won't scroll past the bottom of your content, so you won't be able to centre on your last line (unless you've added a load of newlines to the end of the file, which is obviously a bit gross).

However, there is a way to centre on a line that can be centred on which can be configured in the *Key Bindings* section of Xcode's Preferences (at least in Xcode 8.3, I haven't checked earlier ones). If you filter for "center" you'll see **Center Selection in Visible Area**, and you can assign it to something.

For example, I have assigned it to `Cmd-Alt-Ctrl-K` in the below screenshot.

[image: Xcode preferences screenshot showing location of the Center Selection in Visible Area Key Binding]

Answer (score 0):

Hit (⌃ + L) on Xcode. [Extra characters to hit the min. character count]

Answer (score 0):

This is all changed in modern Xcode, where “overscrolling” is now a feature.